# Нужно сделать множество запросов POST на одну страницу

Tags: java, многопоточность, post, httpclient

Здравствуйте. Есть сайт, в котором необходимо ввести числовое значение с использованием перебора (брутфорс), после того, если оно будет правильное, выведется ссылка на вики. 
Подключение и запрос делаю с помощью HttpClient из org.apache.http. Отгадать число нужно за пол часа. Пытаюсь это сделать с помощью многопоточности, но нормально работает только когда потоков около восьми. Получается ну очень медленно. Как это дело ускорить?

Брутфорс реализовал и могу указывать какое количество значений надо перебрать, то есть в одном потоке перебирается однозначные, во втором двухзначные, в третьем трехзначные и так далее.

Помогите сделать это дело быстрее, если конечно это возможно. Пока что один запрос и ответ на него длится около 1 секунды.

Comment: вы не по длине распределяйте между потоками, а по количеству. а то двухзначных вариантов (для чисел к примеру) 90, а трехзначных 900. Скорость ответа зависит в большей степени от сервера, на нее вы не повлияете. А создав большое число одновременных запросов еще и сервер потенциально подвесить сможете.

Comment: Спасибо. Но все равно не понятно как сделать так чтобы нашло нужный за пол часа. Это прям миссия невыполнима. Даже разделив по количеству все равно переберу мало за это время. главная проблема в том чтобы отправить как можно больше запросов на как можно меньшее время. А это как-то не очень получается.